# Add Css in spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx, spfx-webparts, reactjs

I want to add below CSS in SPFx web-part using states. But unable to do it:

```
div[class^='pageTitle_']
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: try this https://blog.kloud.com.au/2019/05/15/apply-custom-css-to-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-webpart/

Comment: What do you mean by "using states"??

Comment: react states but its not necessary but like to implement inline css  in react.js

Comment: can we check this class by name of page if div[class^='pageTitle_'] =Home display none or show

Answer (score 1):

Create a file , let's say **customCSS.css** inside your component folder and paste the below code :

```
div[class^='pageTitle_']{
  display: none ;
}
```

Now in your main .ts file call this css file with the following syntax on top of the code :

```
require("../../webparts/WebpartName/components/customCSS.css");
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks but i want to add inlince css within reactjs is it possible

Comment: You need to hide the title from modern page using inline css ?

Comment: yes i need it but it affect other pages as well so thought of hiding  set css inline

Comment: this will not impact the other pages, it will impact only on the page where webpart is inserted. I did not come across any way to do it with inline css.

Comment: ok i removed module.scss file and added custom.css but geetin error for @import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore';

Comment: you don't need to delete any file from the project. Just add this file inside component folder as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: adding custom css give me below error anything i am missing Refused to apply style from 'url' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the CSS at end of your webpart .scss file.
[image]

[image]

Comment: yes it is working but if i navigate to another page from navigation same css apply there and hide my title until i refresh it manually any idea why thi behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions, by injecting additional routines in the OnInit or ComponentWillMount method.

One mentioned in comments by @Karthik, by using in your code the utility **SPComponentLoader.loadCss** with an external file.

The second it’s adding inline CSS into the head of the current page such as this sample: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/react-application-injectcss/src/extensions/injectCss/InjectCssApplicationCustomizer.ts